# Android and SQLite using the SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter, helper

I have a SQLite database, and several tables within that datbase. I am developing a DBAdapter for each table within the database. (reference Reto Meier's Professional Android 2 Application Development, Listing 7.1).

I am using the adb shell to interface with the database from the command line and see that the database is being populated as I expect. Occasionally, I want to drop a table so that I can ensure it's being built properly, from scratch.

The problem is that SQLiteOpenHelper only checks to see if the database exists. Is there a typical solution to writing a helper to also see that the table(s) exists? Basically once I drop a table, the helper checks to see that the database exists and assumes all is well.

Also, the CREATE_DATABASE string used in the reference above only creates the one table. Should I consider using the DBAdapter for an adapter to ALL of my tables? That doesn't seem as clean to me.

[Reference Material](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a typical solution to writing
>   a helper to also see that the table(s)
>   exists?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='...' ORDER BY name;
```

(substituting in your table's name for `...`)

If that returns `1`, your table exists. If that returns `0`, your table does not exist.

However, the helper won't help you with that. For testing purposes, I recommend getting rid of the entire database, since in production, you won't be creating individual tables on the fly, either.

Comment: So, I really feel dumb..but what's the shell command to get rid of the db?

Comment: `rm /data/data/your.package.here/databases/your.db`, substituting in appropriate values for `your.package.here` and `your.db`. Or, use the File Manager in DDMS (standalone or Eclipse perspective) and nuke it that way.

Comment: the `rm` will only work in the emulator and on rooted phones. On normal phones you will need to do an `adb uninstall` which will remove the `/data/data/your.package.here` directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally, I want to drop a table
>   so that I can ensure it's being built
>   properly, from scratch.

I have a instrumentation test which drops and recreates **all** tables. A little more work but once done a lot more helpful.

> Is there a typical solution to writing
>   a helper to also see that the table(s)
>   exists?

In addition to what CommonsWare suggested there is also a option to use shell command to get this informations.

```
adb -e shell sqlite3 -batch ${DB_FILE} .table
adb -e shell sqlite3 -batch ${DB_FILE} .schema
```